# How to check if select 1 works or not in hibernate C3P0?

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

I'm working with `hibernate` and `C3P0`and my target is to test if `select 1;` works or not, I want to log `select 1` in my consol.
I had this log in my console but I didn't have `select 1` executed:

```
2020-05-12 13:19:56,365 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO  (AbstractPoolBackedDataSource:462) - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@fbfe8ac5 [ connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@66460a64 [ acquireIncrement -> 1, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1brb47waa2g67nfppp467|33e7dcd8, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 60, initialPoolSize -> 3, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 100, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 50, maxStatements -> 100, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 5, nestedDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@dd22c2a7 [ description -> null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 1brb47waa2g67nfppp467|7944ff00, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.13:3306/jbpm, properties -> {autoReconnect=true, is-connection-validation-required=true, user=******, password=******, autoReconnectForPools=true} ], preferredTestQuery -> select 1;, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> true, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false; userOverrides: {} ], dataSourceName -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 1brb47waa2g67nfppp467|6f2545f6, numHelperThreads -> 3 ]
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>                
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">1200</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">100</property>           
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1;</property>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the application is working, the tests aren't failing. (You have `testConnectionOnCheckout -> true`, so your application would not have Connections if tests were failing.)

However, if you are using a recent c3p0 and a not-ancient (JDBC4 or newer) JDBC driver, you might leave the preferred test query out altogether, and rely upon `Connection.isValid()` which is designed for the purpose.

You can get some logging of c3p0's tests if you set logger `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool` to `TRACE` or equivalent in whatever logging library you are using. Unfortunately, it does not log the test query.